# Building a QuadTree according to population density in Java

Tags: java, google-maps, quadtree

I'm looking for a java code for building a QuadTree according to population density.
Also, I'm using Google maps in my code so if somebody knows how to implement it, that would be very helpful!
Thanx

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with quadtree's but you can use a shortcut and look into a space filling curve. For example a hilbert curve reduces the 2d problem to a 1d problem. A good introduction to space filling curve is Nick quadtree spatial index hilbert curve blog.